# How to install bower component in Meteor-Angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, bower

I'd like to use the following plugin in my Meteor/AngularJS/Ionic application:

https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker

It's available via bower, but when I install it with that my application fails to compile (presumably because it downloads dependencies, `angular`, `ionic`, and a few more, to run, and they're already in my app (using Meteor's packaging system)). I have also tried to ignore those dependencies in the bower.json file.

If I try to just include the files from the `src` folder in that repo, I get an error when opening my app:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionic-timepicker due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionic-timepicker.templates due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ionic-timepicker.templates' is not available!
```

Is there a way that I can use this plugin with Meteor/Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is not related to angular-meteor. It seems that you are not including the library into your application.

Bower only searchs your library and download it, but doesn't import it into your project. Use script tag to include your file.js placed in bower_components folder and make sure you have added the module you downloaded as a depedency of angular.

That's the main reasons why that error happens.

Comment: In meteor you do not want to include using script tags.

Comment: Oh! that's meteor-angular, I was confusing with angular-meteor, the other way round. Are you using bower-meteor package?

Comment: @Thanks. Didn't realize I had to use the bower-meteor package. Installed that and then included ionic-timepicker in the dependencies list and got it to work.